# Is the word "bill" considered an abstract noun or a concrete noun?

Tags: abstract-nouns, concrete-nouns

Is the word "**bill**" considered to be an abstract noun or a concrete noun?

It is not clear to me whether it is an abstract noun because it talks about something that we cannot feel with our senses, or it is a concrete noun because we can touch the paper which represents the bill for payment.

Comment: I don't consider it abstract but concrete. It has a very specific referent that exists in the world, whereas nouns like "sincerity" or "justice" or "promptness" have no such existence.

Comment: It might depend on the context. *Bring me the bill* means bring me the piece of paper containing the amount that is owed. But *I wonder what the bill will come to* is a way of thinking about the total - and total is an abstract noun.